# Как получить список пользователей канала используя telegraf

Tags: node.js, telegraf

Всем привет. Стоит задача получения списка подписчиков телеграм канала использую фрейворк telegraf.

Суть в следующем. Бот ставится в канал и группу. При написании пользователем в группу, бот должен проверить, состоит ли тот в канале. В общем - бот проверки подписки.

Вижу пока способ решения следующий: получать id пользователя и проверять по участникам канала, но вот самих участников канала получить не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь использовать этот медот telegram API https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember

Он проверят вступил ли пользователь с определенным id в определённое сообщество

Comment: Благодарю. Проверю